# Custom Wordpress Widget - 3 Text Fields

Tags: widget, wordpress, custom-widgets

I've found a tutorial http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/ that shows how to create a basic WP Widget with a title field.

Can anyone help me add two more fields to the Widget so I can collect:

- Title
- Content
- A Link

I think I then know how to use this and style it.

Help much appreciated!

Dvent

Answer (score 4):

**Code to add to your file**

If you want to add a textarea for content you can put the following lines into `function form($instance)`:

```
printf(
    '<textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="%1$s" name="%2$s">%3$s</textarea>',
    $this->get_field_id( 'content' ),
    $this->get_field_name( 'content' ),
    $content
);
```

Where `$content` is the content you inserted before.

For a textfield you can you can put the following lines into the samen function:

```
printf( '<p>
        <label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>
        <input class="widefat" id="%1$s" name="%3$s" type="text" value="%4$s" />
    </p>',
    $this->get_field_id( 'link' ),
    __( 'Title:', $this->language ),
    $this->get_field_name( 'link' ),
    esc_attr( $link )
);
```

Where `$link` is the content you inserted before.

Add the following lines into `function update($new_instance, $old_instance)`:

```
$instance['content'] = $new_instance['content'];
$instance['link']    = $new_instance['link'];
```

Add the following lines into `function widget($args, $instance)`:

```
$content = empty( $instance['content'] ) ? '' : wpautop( $instance['content'] );
$link    = empty( $instance['link'] ) ? '' : esc_attr( $instance['link'] );

if ( ! empty( $content ) )
    echo $content;

if ( ! empty ( $link ) )
    echo "<a href='$link'>$link</a>";
```

If you don't want to automaticly add `<p>`'s to your content, simply remove `wpautop`.

**What the functions do**

`function form($instance)` shows the back-end widget form
`function update($new_instance, $old_instance)` sanitizes widget form values as they are saved.
`function widget($args, $instance)` shows the front-end display of widget

So if you want to alter the display of widgets settings window, edit the content of `function form($instance)`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Mike! How would I add additional fields (just <input type="text"> ). Also, which part of the code defines the list they're shown in the Widget settings window?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the help, Had a small issue:
when you save the contents, all the contents dissapear from the form.
so I fixed like this parsing the new fields on the beginning of the : $instance array

```
function form($instance)
    {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 
        'title' => '',
        'bannertext' => '',
        'link' => '' 
    ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $bannertext = $instance['bannertext'];
    $link  = $instance['link'];
```

Then make the printf() contents